# catkin_prepare_release fails with svn upstream

Tags: ros, catkin, svn

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ros-hydro-catkin 0.5.71-0precise-20130720-2204-+0000

```
$ catkin_prepare_release
Prepare the source repository for a release.
Repository type: svn
Found packages: openrtm_aist, hrpsys, rtctree, openrtm_common, openhrp3, rtshell, openrtm_aist_python, rtsprofile
Prepare release of version '3.1.5' [Y/n]?
Warning: the following packages do not have a changelog file or entry for version '3.1.5': hrpsys, openhrp3, openrtm_aist, openrtm_aist_python, openrtm_common, rtctree, rtshell, rtsprofile
Continue without changelogs [y/N]?y
Bump version of all packages from '3.1.4' to '3.1.5'
Could not determine base URL of SVN repository 'https://rtm-ros-robotics.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/openrtm_common'
```

Apparently it fails because the given URL of the repo ends with none of what's accepted by `catkin_prepare_release` ([link to source](https://github.com/ros/catkin/blob/978c7b07dd3fe0cd7bcaef64af26cd5eacf1e332/bin/catkin_prepare_release#L126)). I'm not familiar with `svn` much, but the packages I'm releasing does not directly reside under `trunk`, and no brunch/tag is assumed to be available for the moment (I might be able to use tag though). Then what should I do with this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70054/catkin_prepare_release-fails-with-svn-upstream/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-07-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since the tool has no way to determine the structure of your SVN repository if you do not follow the convention (the SVN base from where you release is "trunk") you have to manually commit the changes and create the tag.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-07-31**:
I see.  Later on I'll figure out the right url for my pkg